# initialize union members - using MS visual studio

Tags: c, data-structures

Need to initialize a union member during compile time.
Reading some articles it seems there is no way other than only defining the first
entry in a union. Unless you use C99 then you can define each union member specifically.

The thing is I use Visual studio 2010 Prof. it seems it does not Support C99 or how can i enable ist? 
Or is there an other way to initialize a union member?

thanks

```
typedef union {
int a;
char *atxt;
} MY_UNION_t;
typedef struct {
int foo;
MY_UNION_t un;
}GEN_DATA_t;

/* need to do following: */
GEN_DATA_t obj1 = {0,1}; /* Okay works */
GEN_DATA_t obj2 = {0,"bla"}; /* Does not work */

/* ISO C99 allows: */
GEN_DATA_t obj3 = {0,.atext="bla"}; /* However MS VS seem not to support this */
```

Comment: You are trying to convert a constant string literal into a non-constant char pointer, aren't you? I don't think it is a good idea in a first place.

Answer (score 5):

When initializing an union, the first named member of the union is the one that will be initialized (ISO 9899:1999 6.7.8 §17).

That is, unless you are using C99 designated initializers like you attempt on the last line, then the member selected is the one that will be initialized. But C99 is apparently not supported by VS.

Solve the problem by changing the union declaration to:

```
typedef union {
char *atxt;
int a;
} MY_UNION_t;

/* make sure that the string "bla" isn't allocated in read-only memory, 
   since you intend to point at it with a non-const pointer */
char bla[] = "bla";  

GEN_DATA_t obj2 = {0, bla};
```

Answer (score 0):

Windows does not fully support C99, only selected features, as it is mainly a C++ compiler.

Here you go: 
http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/485416/support-c99